# How to reproduce and prevent ESOCKETTIMEDOUT in Node JS

Tags: node.js, sockets, request

At some random times, on our production server, we face such type of timeouts and the server crashes.

```
Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/request/request.js:816:19)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:180:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (domain.js:422:20)
at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:703:34)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:180:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:422:20)
at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:396:8)
at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:267:5)
```

I have gone though a lot of blogs and QAs. To summarize, it's read timeout when the caller doesn't get next bytes of response within some specific time limit. From the [offical docs (request-npm)](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback), we can see -

`Read timeout: Time to wait for a server to send response headers (and start the response body) before aborting the request.
Connection timeout: Sets the socket to timeout after timeout milliseconds of inactivity. Note that increasing the timeout beyond the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will not have any effect (the default in Linux can be anywhere from 20-120 seconds)`

However I am trying to reproduce it in local linux machine with a HTTP request to my own Node JS server. I am able to get `ETIMEDOUT` which is connection timeout but I can't get `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT` error reproduced. In my destination server I had used this simple script with Express JS as an attempt to get this error.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.write('sample string');
    // Do nothing, let the req wait
});
```

Therefore does anybody knows a simple approach to get this reproduced? Also I would like to know how to handle this error instead of having it as uncaught exception.

Thanks!

Comment: ESOCKETIMEDOUT means that there are too many async request not being fulfilled. Are you making request to another server or crawling websites inside your production server ?

Comment: Not really! It's really less frequent for me. That's why I am having trouble with finding the point of issue. How can I catch this error?

Comment: i am also noticing this recently. anyone can help ?